# middleware on res.render() when using a lot of routes

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I've created a webpage to use it locally. I have a ton of routes like the ones shown below -- 31 `.ejs` files and 3 `.html` files. (They are all in the same "views" folder).

```
//app.js - using node and express
    app.get('/page1', function(req, res){
        res.render('page1');
    });
    app.get('/page2', function(req, res){
        res.sendFile('views/page2.html', { root: __dirname });
    });
```

I use an `app.get` for each and every one of these files. I've had a feeling it wasn't DRY code, and so now I'm trying to figure out a more elegant and optimal way to achieve the same result.

- I know that many `res.sendFile();` could be replaced with a single `express.static()` middleware statement. I usually use `express.static()` on a "public" folder which I use to save all my css files -- like this `app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));`. But I still don't see how I could use this to simplify all my `res.sendFile()`.
- As for the many `res.render();` routes, I know that if I don't pass any customized data I could probably replace them with a single middleware that handles either a whole directory of template files (and their corresponding routes) or a list of files. I just don't know how I would do that.

Any help is very much appreciated, thanks!!

---

[UPDATE]

> - richie
>   - node_modules
>   - public
>     - css files, images, etc
>   - views
>     - partials
>       - all partial files
>     - programmingPublic
>       - all ejs files from a same topic
>     - other files (html & other ejs)
>   - appjs
>   - packagejson
>   - package-lockjson

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const path = require('path');

const app = express(); 

// Body Parser Middleware
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false}));

// engine
app.set("view engine", "ejs");

// Set static path
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

const fs = require('fs');

function renderStatic(dir) {
    return function(req, res, next) {
        let target = path.join(dir, req.path);
        fs.access(target, fs.constants.R_OK, function(err) {
            if (err) {
                // file not found, just move on
                next();
            } else {
                res.render(target);
            }
        });
    }
}

app.use(renderStatic(path.join(__dirname, "views/programmingPublic")));
```

Below is the format of my side-menu: (all these files are inside "programmingPublic" folder)

```
<a href="/programming" class="title">Programming</a>
<li><a href="/c">C</a></li>
<li><a href="/cpp">C++</a></li>
<li><a href="/python">Python</a></li>
<li><a href="/javascript">JavaScript</a></li>
<li><a href="/php">PHP</a></li>
```

Comment: In this directory hierarchy, where is `__dirname`?  And, when you have a link like `/javascript` in your side-menu, what file are you hoping for that to display?  And, where is it?

Comment: I thought `__dirname` was the "richie" folder since it's the root of all files & folders. `/javascript` is the name of the page -- I save info about the language on it.

Comment: all these files (programming, c, cpp, python, javascript, php) are inside the programmingPublic folder

Comment: Are you trying to render files that have no file extension?

Comment: they are all `.ejs` files. I use `app.set("view engine", "ejs");` on the app.js file (like I showed above) and it always works.

Comment: I added .ejs at the end of `<li><a href="/c.ejs">C</a></li>` and got this message: Could not find the include file "partials/header".

Comment: Should I add my partials folder to the renderStatic function?

Comment: I solved it!! I just had to change my header to `<% include ../partials/xheader %>`
and add the extension to my files, so now it's `/page1.ejs`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a bunch of pages that need to call `res.render()`, but aren't passing custom options to each render, then you could isolate all those templates in their own directory and then use some middleware like this:

```
const path = require('path');
const fs = require('fs');

function renderStatic(dir, options) {
    const regex = /^\.|\.\.|\/\.|\\\./;
    options = options || {};

    return function(req, res, next) {
        let target = path.join(dir, req.path);
        if (options.ext && !path.extname(target)) {
           target = target + options.ext;
        }
        // don't allow leading dot or double dot anywhere in the path
        if (regex.test(target)) {
           next();
           return;
        }
        fs.access(target, fs.constants.R_OK, function(err) {
            if (err) {
                // file not found, just move on
                next();
            } else {
                res.render(target);
            }
        });
    }
}

app.use(renderStatic(path.join(__dirname, "renderPublic"), {ext: ".ejs"}));
```

Note, you must isolate these template files in their own directory so that other files are not found there.

For safety completeness, this code also needs to filter out `.` and `..` items in the path like `express.static()` does to prevent an attacker from going up your directory hierarchy to get access to other files than those in the render static directory.

---

Then, for the routes you are using `res.sendFile()` and no other logic, just isolate those HTML files in their own directory and point `express.static()` at that directory.  Then, the `express.static()` middleware will find a matching HTML file in that directory and do `res.sendFile()` for you automatically, exactly the same as it does for your CSS files.

Comment: I'm getting a "cannot get" error message. I've tried moving the folder to the root directory (where the app.js is located), and inside the root/views folder. Is it because I already have a `app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));` and a `const path = require('path');`? I've also tried changing `const path` to `var path`

Comment: I've also tried changing this part `app.use(renderStatic(path.join(__dirname, "renderPublic")));` to the top of the code on the app.js file

Comment: I tried changing from this  `<a href="/page1">page1</a>` to this  `<a href="renderPublic/page1">page1</a>`

Comment: @richie - No.  Don't add `renderPublic` to the HTML page at all.  That's local to the server only.  That's where you PUT the template files on your server - not anything to do with the public URL for that.  Do you understand the difference between the public URL (that the server gets a request for) and the directory that the middleware looks in for a matching file?

Comment: @richie - Using the exact code in my answer, you would create a sub-directory under `__dirname` (where you app is located) and put the template files in there.  But, you can obviously put them wherever you want and just pass the right path to them to the `renderStatic()` middleware so it knows where to look for matches.

Comment: I was just trying everything to see if it would work, I changed it back

Comment: I'm using the same code you wrote with "views/renderPublic" instead

Comment: I already had a `const path = require('path');` in my code, so I just commented out your const path...but everything else is the same

Comment: I'm still getting Cannot GET /page1

Comment: @richie - To help you debug your code on this, I would need to see a sketch of the file hierarchy relative to `__dirname`,  see exactly where in that hierarchy you put which template files, see exactly which URLs you are putting into the browser and see your actual server-side code.  This works with the right combination of all of those.  Can't debug it without seeing the whole picture.

Comment: @richie - Perhaps you should make a new question.

Comment: I just updated the question, I didn't see this last comment. I've added all the relevant information in the update, but if you take a look and think it would be too much hassle to answer in comments I'll ask a new question

Comment: @richie - I modified my code so you don't need the `.ejs` on the URLs.

Comment: I'm just now seeing your last comment..I actually asked a new question and posted above so you can get a feel of the issue. BUt I'm gonna check your modified code now. I can always delete my question

Comment: @richie - Notice that my latest version also has the security fix that prevents paths that walk UP the hierarchy with things like `./` in the path.

Comment: I deleted the other question. Hey, thank you so much, mate! I have to admit, I don't fully understand all the pieces of the `renderStatic` function, but I see that you disabled all `.` and `..` items in the path which is awesome haha

Comment: Yeah, I noticed it. I know I'm just using it locally, but even if it was online I still don't know how someone could get to my other files

Comment: @richie - By using an URL like this: `/../../../app.js`.  This would be capable of looking on your hard disk ABOVE the `renderPublic` directory and fetching those files which is not what you want anyone to be able to do.  That's why we disable it if there are any leading dots in any path segment.

Comment: got it! Thanks again! I have one last question that is sort of unrelated to the main subject here, but it's quite simple to answer it. I have a "backup" folder inside the "richie" folder (same hierarchy as the app.js file) that has a bunch of random files like e-books and images which are not at all used in the application itself. Does it slow down my application since it's in the same folder as the `app.js`?

Comment: @richie - No, it doesn't slow anything down.  Nothing should be looking there.